# InvalidOperationException when trying to use Stack.Pop()

Tags: unity-game-engine, stack, depth-first-search

I'm getting an exception that makes absolutely no sense whatsoever. I'm trying to use this depth-first algorithm to make a random maze:

http://www.mazeworks.com/mazegen/mazetut/

I have most everything implemented, but when I run the program, I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current
>   state of the object System.Collections.Generic.Stack
>   1[UnityEngine.GameObject].Pop()

The unfortunate thing is that the stack doesn't show up in the inspector, so I can't look at the 'current state' of the stack.

This error also doesn't occur when using the debugger.

Here's my code:

```
/***************************************************************************************/
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MazeGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] m_totalCells;       // all the cells in the level
    public GameObject[] m_walls;            // all the walls in the level
    public List<GameObject> m_visited;      // list of each visited cell
    public Stack<GameObject> m_cellStack;   // last-in, first-out stack for generating the maze

    public GameObject m_currentCell;        // the cell currently being looked at

    public int m_visitedCells = 0;          // how many cells have been looked at

    public bool m_puzzleCreated;            // has the puzzle been made yet

    /*****************************************************************************/
    /*
        Description:
            Use this for initialization.

        Parameters:
            - none

        Return:
            - none
    */
    /*****************************************************************************/
    void Start()
    {
        m_totalCells = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Cell");
        m_walls = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Wall");

        //initialize the stack
        m_visited = new List<GameObject>();
    }

    /*****************************************************************************/
    /*
        Description:
            Make a random maze using the depth-field algorithm.

        Parameters:
            - none

        Return:
            - none
    */
    /*****************************************************************************/
    void GeneratePuzzle()
    {
        // make sure all the cells have found their neighbors and walls
        foreach(GameObject cell in m_totalCells)
        {
            cell.GetComponent<Cell>().FindAdjacents();
            cell.GetComponent<Cell>().FindWalls();
            cell.GetComponent<Cell>().FindNeighbors();
        }

        m_cellStack = new Stack<GameObject>();

        // grab a randon cell
        int randomizer = Random.Range(0, m_totalCells.Length);
        m_currentCell = m_totalCells[randomizer];
        m_visitedCells = 1;

        while(m_visitedCells < m_totalCells.Length)
        {
            m_visited.Add(m_currentCell);

            if(m_totalCells[randomizer].GetComponent<Cell>().FindNeighbors() == true)
            {
                m_cellStack.Push(m_currentCell);
                m_currentCell = m_currentCell.GetComponent<Cell>().BreakWall();
                m_visitedCells++;
            }

            else
            {
                    /*********************************/
                    /*    This is where I Pop()      */
                    /*********************************/            
                m_currentCell = m_cellStack.Pop();
            }
        }

        foreach(GameObject wall in m_walls)
        {
            if(wall.gameObject.GetComponent<Wall>().m_destroyed == true)
            {
                Destroy(wall);
            }
        }
    }

    /*****************************************************************************/
    /*
        Description:
            Update is called once a frame.

        Parameters:
            - none

        Return:
            - none
    */
    /*****************************************************************************/
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && m_puzzleCreated == false)
        {
            m_puzzleCreated = true;
            GeneratePuzzle();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According with [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.pop%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) this exception happens when the stack is empty.

If you are having trouble debugging than it's better to just add a `UnityEngine.Debug.Log(m_currentCell.name);` inside the *if/else* blocks to track the state of the Stack, or simply print the whole Stack every time before entering the *if* statement.